# Concurrency in PHP with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I have a problem of concurrency in  my php application with mysql database. I have a process by which the application brings data from a sql server 2005 database  and inserts these in my mysql database, first checking that these data are not currently exist.. the problem is that this process is executed by many users, and if two people run it simultaneously,i have concurrency problems, and the application does not realize that just another terminal has entered the data.
Let me give a simple example to make you understand:

```
$mylastPatientId = 1000;
//SEARCH FOR NEW PATIENTES IN SQL SERVER THAT AR NOT IN MYSQL
$sql="SELECT ID,FULLNAME FROM PATIENTS WHERE ID > $mylastPatientId ";
$result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql)or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));
while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
{
    $id = odbc_result($result, "ID");
    $fullname = odbc_result($result, "FULLNAME");
    $resultMySql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patients where id = $id ", $conexion);
    if (mysql_affected_rows() ==0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO patients (id,fullname) values ($id,$fullname);", $conexion);
    }
}
```

please note that this is just a simplified example of a much larger process that I have, but that's the idea. code block is newly invented and not proven.
good, the problem here is that when two terminals simultaneously perform this process, this does not detect that another terminal has already been inserted to the patient, and therefore, the patient is inserted twice.

Comment: What database engine are you using with MySQL?

Comment: Start by swapping to InnodDB then, which is ACID compliant (MyISAM isn't) and uses row locking rather than table locking; then use a single INSERT IGNORE statement rather than separate SELECT and INSERT statements

Comment: Recreate your table with a new name as InnoDB, transfer data from old table to new table, drop old table, rename new table to old table name

Comment: did not work. still duplicating the records.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your table? If so, what indexes?

Comment: I do not know. what indexes should i have?

Comment: Well to start, you should have a unique primary key index on `id`... other indexes should depend on the columns that you use in your queries, or any foreign key constraints that you have

Comment: INSERT IGNORE will only work when you try to insert a record with an id (unique PK) that matches a record that already exists with the same unique PK.... this really is databases 101 level

Comment: well, it seems that no one is understanding me. I know what a database is and how to do to verify a record does not exist. I know what is a primary key. the problem is that it seems that each terminal sees absolutely nothing of what makes while another terminal in the database.

Comment: If you do an INSERT in MySQL, specifying a value in the PK field list, and a PK with that same value already exists in the database (or indeed any Unique key, not just the primary key), then MySQL should always give you a "duplicate key" error..... INSERT IGNORE basically tells MySQL that if it hits a duplicate key error, do nothing

Comment: then I will try to define a more complex primary key. thank you

Comment: Or try a unique key that genuinely matches some of the data that you're trying to insert

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in my opinion is to create a unique constraint on `patients.id`, and use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT`

Comment: I can not do this. actually the table that insert is not of patients, patient is just an example. My table is a queue of care in a hospital. the patient can come back another time. the key of my table is an auto-incremental queue_id